# APT seems broken in my Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

I am a beginner in Ubuntu.

Just last week I have installed Ubuntu18.
I have a dual boot machine on new laptop with Secure boot switched-on (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.5).

I have NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 in my laptop, so I tried to install Nvidia drivers by following the steps mentioned here: https://gist.github.com/bitsurgeon/b0f4440984c9e60dcd8fe8bbc346c029

But now, neither the NVIDIA driver is installed, nor my apt seems to work.
Whenever I try to install something using `sudo apt install <package-name>`, I get this error constantly.

```
$ sudo apt install aptitude:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude:i386 : Depends: aptitude-common:i386 (= 0.8.10-6ubuntu1)
                 Depends: libapt-pkg5.0:i386 (>= 1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libboost-iostreams1.65.1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libboost-system1.65.1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcwidget3v5:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libncursesw5:i386 (>= 6) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0v5:i386 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libsqlite3-0:i386 (>= 3.6.5) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxapian30:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: libparse-debianchangelog-perl:i386 but it is not installable
 libnvidia-gl-450 : Depends: libnvidia-common-450 but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-gl-450:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-common-450:i386
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

It seems my apt is broken, how do I fix this?
As suggested above, I have tried to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, but I get this warning:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  g++-6 libaccinj64-9.1 libcublas9.1 libcudart9.1 libcufft9.1 libcufftw9.1 libcurand9.1
  libcusolver9.1 libcusparse9.1 libnppc9.1 libnppial9.1 libnppicc9.1 libnppicom9.1 libnppidei9.1
  libnppif9.1 libnppig9.1 libnppim9.1 libnppist9.1 libnppisu9.1 libnppitc9.1 libnpps9.1
  libnvblas9.1 libnvgraph9.1 libnvidia-common-450-server libnvrtc9.1 libnvtoolsext1 libnvvm3
  libthrust-dev libvdpau-dev ocl-icd-opencl-dev opencl-c-headers python3-debconf
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  aptitude:i386 aptitude-common libapt-pkg5.0:i386 libboost-filesystem1.65.1:i386
  libboost-iostreams1.65.1:i386 libboost-system1.65.1:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libcwidget3v5:i386
  libgcrypt20:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgpm2:i386 liblz4-1:i386 liblzma5:i386 libncursesw5:i386
  libnvidia-common-450 libsigc++-2.0-0v5:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libsystemd0:i386 libudev1:i386
  libuuid1:i386 libxapian30:i386
Suggested packages:
  aptitude-doc-en:i386 | aptitude-doc:i386 apt-xapian-index:i386 debtags:i386 tasksel:i386
  libcwidget-dev:i386 rng-tools:i386 gpm:i386 xapian-tools:i386
Recommended packages:
  libparse-debianchangelog-perl:i386 apt:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apt apt-utils skypeforlinux ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
  update-manager update-notifier update-notifier-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  aptitude-common libapt-pkg5.0:i386 libboost-filesystem1.65.1:i386 libboost-iostreams1.65.1:i386
  libboost-system1.65.1:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libcwidget3v5:i386 libgcrypt20:i386 libgpg-error0:i386
  libgpm2:i386 liblz4-1:i386 liblzma5:i386 libncursesw5:i386 libnvidia-common-450
  libsigc++-2.0-0v5:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libsystemd0:i386 libudev1:i386 libuuid1:i386
  libxapian30:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  aptitude:i386
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt
1 upgraded, 20 newly installed, 9 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 6,130 kB/6,140 kB of archives.
After this operation, 295 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?]
```

Without knowing the consequence, I shouldn't change things, thus I am asking here if somebody could point out what to do.
Or if there is a good tutorial on apt, so that I could understand how it works and how I can fix my problem.

Looking for to every solution.

**Edit:**
Output of `uname -a`:

```
$ uname -a
Linux mehta-hp 5.4.0-52-generic #57~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 14:04:49 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of `gedit /var/log/apt/history.log`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/knfP2rhVbQ/

Output of `apt list --installed`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/G2tTz3v26b/

Comment: Is your system i386 or amd64?   Also FYI:  Ubuntu has both *yy* releases (eg. Ubuntu Core 18) and *yy.mm* releases (eg. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server/Desktop), and they are different products. Ubuntu 18 implies to me & many as Ubuntu Core 18, which doesn't use `apt` as it's *snap* only, being a different system to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: @guiverc I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and it is amd64 release.

Comment: Why are you trying to install `aptitude` in i386 architecture if you're running amd64?  Have you enabled multiarch?  (and more importantly do you really need it?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch

Comment: @guiverc I am not trying to install anything, I just ran `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430`, here it automatically went to install that package which it was not able to download. I thought Nvidia requires i386 libs. Thus i tried running it manually. If it is not required, how do i remove it?

Comment: Hey Mihir Mehta! Please paste the output of `uname -a` in your question (use [edit] feature to edit your question). Also, let's look into your apt log. Paste this in terminal: `gedit /var/log/apt/history.log` and press Enter. Now, Text Editor app will open  a text file. Copy the contents of it and paste it in a pastebin (like https://paste.ubuntu.com/). Share the link of the pastebin. Don't forget to tag me (like this: @technastic_tc) if you're replying to my comment.

Comment: @technastic_tc please find the output for `uname -a` in the question. Also, the output for `gedit /var/log/apt/history.log` can be found here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/knfP2rhVbQ/

Appreciate your time!

Comment: @MihirMehta Also share the output of `apt list --installed`. (Use pastebin)

Comment: @technastic_tc as requested by you, please find the output of `apt list --installed` at this link https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/G2tTz3v26b/

Comment: @MihirMehta can you please run `sudo apt purge aptitude:i386 libnvidia-gl-450 libnvidia-gl-450:i386`?

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog I tried that earlier, no effect.

Comment: @MihirMehta It would be great if you can also share the contents of `gedit /var/log/apt/term.log`. One more thing.. Paste this in terminal: `history > history.txt` and press Enter. Now there will be a new file saved in your home directory named as "history.txt". Also share the contents of that file. (Use pastebin)

Comment: @MihirMehta Paste the output of `sudo apt update` in your question (use the [edit] feature).